# Your payment could not be taken. Please try again or use a different payment method. PayPal Validation Failed / braintree

Tags: magento2.4.6, braintree

we have a problem since update to 2.4.6 and braintree 4.5.0. It seems to occur only for customers, who already bought something a while ago.

The first payment works, Then, after some days, the second payment fails.

As i heard from customers, they did not log in and others ordered both times only as guest.

We have amasty checkout.

[image]

Staus at braintree:

[image]